# How should this interface be written or implemented to avoid the TS2322 error where target allows only 1

Tags: angular, typescript, interface

I'm having an issue with declaring an interface where a property is an array of an {}.

This is the interface I defined

```
export interface GlobalEventRegistration {
  'sourceName': string,
  'listenFor': [
    {
      'sourceName': string,
      'eventName': string
    }
  ]
}
```

My code to implement.

```
const registration: GlobalEventRegistration = {
    sourceName: this._className,
    listenFor: [
      {
        sourceName: 'MapComponent',
        eventName: 'test'
      },
      {
        sourceName: 'SomeComponent',
        eventName: ''
      }
    ]
  }
```

The error from the IDE

> TS2322: Type '[{ sourceName: string; eventName: string; }, {
> sourceName: string; eventName: string; }]' is not assignable to type
> '[{ sourceName: string; eventName: string; }]'.   Source has 2
> element(s) but target allows only 1.  GlobalEventRegistration.ts(16,
> 3): The expected type comes from property 'listenFor' which is
> declared here on type 'GlobalEventRegistration'

I'm not clear on why or how to get it to allow me to have the array of inner {} for the 'listenFor'.

Thanks for looking.

Comment: The code you have declares a `tuple` of a single element, if you're interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just try this directory type interface

```
export interface GlobalEventRegistration {
  'sourceName': string,
  'listenFor': 
    {
      'sourceName': string,
      'eventName': string
    }[],
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I would not have expected the interface to be the issue. I thought it was in how I was implementing the use of the interface. It fixed my code. Thank you.